# LSTM / GRU weights during test time

Tags: time-series, lstm, rnn, pytorch, gru

I am working on a historic time series dataset and using RNN, LSTM, GRU models, and I didn't find an answer **if in test time, the h (or h, c) weights should be zeors for each batch?**

If the weights should be zero, what they should be? the last updated weights from the training?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The initial weights of h for GRU and h,c for LSTM are are often set to zeros, setting random weights is also an option. Also people have tried to learn the initial hidden states.

Since the hidden states are updated with every cell, if your sequences are long enough, it would not make a big difference how you initialize the hidden states.

Comment: Thanks, In the training I initialize the weights to zero, however, in test / validation time (model.eval()), the weights also should be zero?

Comment: @YuvalAsher, Yes. I think this is a good approach.